# K-resolved transmission spectrum

Tags: transmission

I want to calculate k-resolved transmission spectrum for device, scattering region made of 13 Arm chair graphene nanoribbon repeating along z direction, under non-equllibrium green function method. I have tight binding hamiltonian for scatter region and I use one unitcell of nanoribbon as left & right lead. How to make transmisson T k dependent.

I need mathematical equations.